# How to put limit on the message size for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am looking for something similar to https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html
for the message size of each message in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not support this at this time. Version `3.8.0` will support a global maximum message size across all queues that could be used ([link](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/1812)).